# Unexpected responses from Office365 REST API

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

We have a service that fetches emails for users using the Office365 REST API. When the user makes this call to our service:

1. We first make a call to get the messages including the attachment metadata, but not the actual attachment content/bytes.
2. Based on the attachment metadata, if the content size is under a certain threshold, we make subsequent calls to get the attachment content.

Therefore, our calls look like the following:

1. Get the list of messages using `GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/Inbox/messages/?$expand=Attachments($Select=Id,Name,ContentType,Size)`
2. For messages for which we need to download attachments, invoke the `GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments` API on individual messageIds that are returned in step 1. E.g.:

   - `GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/message_id_1/attachments`
   - `GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/message_id_2/attachments`

The problem we're facing is that for certain users/messages, the calls to get attachments return the following error:

`{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidAttachmentId","message":"The specified attachment Id is invalid."}}`

This failure seems odd since we're not specifying individual attachmentIds. The messageId must also be correct since it is from the list of messages that was previously obtained in step 1. Is there a problem in the way we're invoking the REST API?

I understand that there may be a possibility that the attachment is available after the call to get messages, but is no longer available during the call to get attachments. However, we've seen these failures pretty consistently for some users/messages.

I'd appreciate any info to help us unblock this situation. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here are the response headers for such a failure:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
request-id: eb45663c-e081-4f68-aa99-d4a81fd3ef46
X-CalculatedFETarget: BN6PR07CU002.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 400,400
X-FEProxyInfo: BN6PR07CA0033.NAMPRD07.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-CalculatedBETarget: SN2PR03MB2349.namprd03.prod.outlook.com
OData-Version: 4.0
X-DiagInfo: SN2PR03MB2349
X-BEServer: SN2PR03MB2349
X-FEServer: BN6PR07CA0033,BN3PR16CA0037
Cache-Control: private
Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 18:45:06 GMT
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=33513ff33c354ad0b92a59b852d79b14; path=/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: If you can provide the full response headers of one of these error responses I can see if what I can find out.

Comment: Thank you, Jason! I've added the response headers in my post.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to ask for more, but can you provide the attachment IDs from the message AND the corresponding response headers? In other words, the attachment IDs shown in the JSON response from your first request (with the expand), then the response headers from the failing request for that same message?